# A better way to update C++ application for windows

Tags: c++, dll

I'm trying to develop `C++` application for a client. So far, i have added the basic functionalities and it works as expected but i will likely to gradually grow the application in future (i.e. adding more feature to it) and the client will likely to update those feature in their app. Now my questions are the following:

1. For adding feature, i have decided to add features to a `dll` and the client will likely replace the old `dll` with the new one (in order to use latest features). Is there a better approach for updating `C++` app?
2. Why some developer use ordinal values instead of function names while exporting symbols, whats the benefit of using ordinal values other than less binary file size ?

I don't want my client to recompile/link the app, i just want to keep the updating process as smooth as possible. Need advice.

P.S:
Environment = Windows + Visual Studio

Comment: why not just redistribute the entire binary instead of updating via dlls? doing it via dlls sounds rather error-prone

Comment: Please, note that a DLL may not be replaced while it is loaded in a process. Unloading the old DLL might help. Otherwise, you have to stop the application, to replace the DLL and to start the application again.

Comment: FYI: [SF: Replacing .dll files while the application is running?](https://serverfault.com/q/503721)

Comment: it may be a bit tricky to add functionality in the way you describe, sometimes your main program maybe wants to call the new functionality? it is better to keep things simple, distributing a complete setup will be easier for you in the long run. it makes it also easier for the user, he doesnt have to install twice base version + dll update

Comment: Actually the client doesn't need to download the entire app every-time some feature is added (or the client maybe doesn't want to stop the program and install new one). The main program can call future functionalities (which are not present yet) and I thought i will just transfer him/her the latest dll everytime and that's will be it.

Comment: I would use dll replacement approach if I had a plugin-based application, when base functionality is expanded by additional plugins. Like browsers or photoshop. And the API for plugins is fixed. But not all apllications fall good into this pattern. If your application heavily relies on dll then most probably adding a feature would make you change API and recomplile DLLs and main exe.

Comment: Considering updating a whole application. Once I wrote a small updater program. The main application runs it as a separate process while running. The updater checks if there is a new version available and replies to the main application. Then the main application can indicate to the user that there is an update available, which will be installed at restart. The application modifies the startup script, so the updater is launched first. It replaces exe and dll, makes backups, alters the script again and launches the main application. May be there are existing solutions on the github.

Comment: If you make it a web-app you won't have to deal with client deployment at all - they click refresh and get the latest version of your app. IMO, UI in C++ is too labour intensive and hence expensive and least portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vasilij way is the way to go. If you update only de `DLL`, how you application will know that there are new functions to call? You have to dynamically adapt your menus and so on.

Just create an `exe` stub that runs the real application (may be in a subprocess it can kill) and update the whole app (not the stub) and `DLL`s when necessary. That stub can check for updates also and suggest the restart after downloading.